# Python - how to create a list of tuple from a single list

Tags: python

How do I create a single list of tuple such as `B_tuple_list = [(3,2), (2,1), (1,0), (0,5), (5,4)]` from a single python list such as `A_python_list = [3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4]`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using **`zip`**:

```
a_list = [3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4]
tuple_list = [(x, y) for x, y in zip(a_list, a_list[1:])]

# [(3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 5), (5, 4)]
```

Or simply,

```
tuple_list = list(zip(a_list, a_list[1:]))
```

Answer (score 3):

May be you can try something like below with `list comprehension`:

```
a_list = [3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4]
tuple_list = [(a_list[i], a_list[i+1]) for i in range(len(a_list)-1)]
print(tuple_list)
```

Result:

```
[(3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 5), (5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip)

```
l = [3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4]
print(list(zip(l, l[1:])))
# [(3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 5), (5, 4)]
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution provided in the [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) uses almost no intermediate storage:

```
from itertools import tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return list(zip(a, b))

print(pairwise([1, 2, 3, 4])) # [(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```

By removing the cast to a `list`, this can be made to return a light-weigth iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehensions.

```
>>> a = [3, 2, 1, 0, 5, 4]
>>> b = [(a[x], a[x+1]) for x in range(len(a))]
>>> print b
[(3, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 5), (5, 4)]
```